# Windows Server 2008 - Setting Up DNS and Web Server (IIS) to host personal website?

Tags: php, timeout, hosting, ip-address

Okay, I have a server, (Windows Server 2008 R2 to be more precise) and I have installed PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, for web hosting purposes.

- I have set up a static ip address internally.
- I have installed the role DNS and Web Server (IIS) role.
- I now set up my forward looking zone as my chosen domain.
- I set up the nameservers as ns1.domain.co.uk with my IP address which I found from whatismyip.org.

However, when I type my IP address, it times out with an error (Timeout Error). Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Also I have seen that most websites have multiple nameservers, which are apparently mirror IP addresses which all redirect to one IP address.

Also, I can locally connect using the IP address 192.168.0.8, however, I want to put my website online/live on the internet.

Can anyone help me with this?

-- Regards

Answer (score 0):

You missed a step, which is to forward your IP (you found from found from whatismyip.org)  port 80  to  192.168.0.8 port 80.   To do that, login to your router,  forward port 80 to 192.168.0.8's port 80